# How is atomic_flag implemented?

Tags: c++, arm, x86-64, atomic, stdatomic

How is `atomic_flag` is implemented? It feels to me that on x86-64 it is equivalent to `atomic_bool`anyway, but it is just a guess. Might the x86-64 implementation be any different from arm or x86?

Comment: _"...Unlike all specializations of std::atomic, it is guaranteed to be lock-free..."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag  And as @IgorTandetnik says you need to look at your implementation.

Comment: If the source code for the standard library is available (very likely) then you can always check it.

Comment: Very well, thank you!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unless that just contains some OS API call ;) Then you have to check your OS source ugh

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: Possibly some ancient ARM CPU might not support `ldrex` / `strex` LL/SC or `dmb ish` memory barriers, and might need a system call, but that would be absolute garbage for performance.  x86 all the way back to 8086 has had sufficient atomic operation support to inline these, so an implementation that made 100x slower by making a system call would be total garbage.

Comment: @PeterCordes Didn't suggest otherwise. We're talking about how you can find out what the calls resolve to

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: `atomic_flag` is required to be lock-free; resolving to a system call probably doesn't count.  A user-space library helper function sure, maybe.  But I think we can rule out a system call.  Or would we count it as lock-free if a single-core system disabled interrupts temporarily to make a short sequence of instructions atomic wrt. interrupts and thus context switches?

Comment: @PeterCordes This is off-topic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 "_This is off-topic_" how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, on normal CPUs where `atomic<bool>` and `atomic<int>` are also lock-free, it's pretty much like `atomic<bool>`, using the same instructions.  (x86 and x86-64 have the same set of atomic operations available.)

You might think that it would always use x86 `lock bts` or `lock btr` to set / reset (clear) a single bit, but it can be more efficient to do other things (especially for a function that returns a bool instead of branching on it).  The object is a whole byte so you can just store or exchange the whole byte.  (And if the ABI guarantees that the value is always `0` or `1`, you don't have to booleanize it before returning the result as a `bool`)

**GCC and clang compile `test_and_set` to a byte exchange, and clear to a byte store of `0`.**  We get (nearly) identical asm for `atomic_flag` `test_and_set` as `f.exchange(true);`

```
#include <atomic>

bool TAS(std::atomic_flag &f) {
    return f.test_and_set();
}

bool TAS_bool(std::atomic<bool> &f) {
    return f.exchange(true);
}


void clear(std::atomic_flag &f) {
    //f = 0; // deleted
    f.clear();
}

void clear_relaxed(std::atomic_flag &f) {
    f.clear(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void bool_clear(std::atomic<bool> &f) {
    f = false; // deleted
}
```

[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAGYAHKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYlysAHVAsLqtHqGJuY%2BfgF09o4uRu6enFZKKmp0DATMxATBxqaWisqYqoHpmQTRzm4eXooZWTmh%2BQp15Q6VcdWJAJSKqAbEyBwA5FJmDsiGWADU4mY6zERGeBJm2OIADACCG5uuqPpTACqbDBDN6CAgC6hLyAD6VMLAM5IAbFRdMwDssltT/1NiJgCP1aFMqAA6AiYZp3EToO5KAgQLqzX7bL4AER2Oz2B2ODDueNYZwIFyui2Wsx0xNm2Be70%2B4h%2BOwBgOBoPBEMwAA9kAgRMBMBACMQDJhUWZ0czsVscVsAG6oPDoKYTTCZUnk663B5PBkfb7otkAehNVBmZkxU3WaKmZqmWHY0PQrIBkPVmsl0qx8s2SpVavYmTuQOEPMw6C1lx1yz1zGeUkZRrd/w9weI0ZARkwRhIAE87iQsMRQ8pmBH0N6cb65YrlariXdPZnzjHKSsaftWHSDUyWX93ZbrVQ2Eo7Q6ncDIzXZdstkMeqwQEMAKxDUimIbrDeoFc6ORyKYKPoDTAvMycDcEFc7ro9ADW5jMEM4q%2B4ZnWr2476%2Bf7MZhCCu3AbluO6kHuQwbgoIDrKQN7boupBwLAMCICgNzeHg7BkBQEBoEYWE4SAwAAJySKQVDYdCxAwRAri3hurgOJk%2BYrlepAETm9AAPK0KwbGIaQWBGIK7CMcJeBAsUCowhJvJFAY0LsRuDjQsuQmsHgrjEKxehYCp8HEHgRgqT0ND0EwbAcDw/CCMIogoIeMhCNpMGQD0qDeKktAwUMAC0PFmNBhTFBoEA2A0picNY2gVLE8SCL4/g%2BVFSURD58VVAkBQpCULRpTFyRFD5pRZFlHQ5c0ZSFbUZQVYlnA9Ce/SDFwS4ruum4SZBPIWK8/nflMwDIMgUykRCkhTBAuCECQF4xVMeiEdhHgLZ8B4yHI16MfepBPgBEKrpwkhmK86ySJwiQWKRZjcLwGkgaQpmrnBYG7iu0GwfBu3IWhEBIARREeOQlBA6tngTIKpHrHBVGsDRdEMUJzG0KxhlcVoBB8QJEkiWJwzgfg0lqLJfngQpyBKcMHFqcoElaTpekYDT17GaZQxXuZdCMCw4m2QID2Ck5W0uYz7kohB3mBH5gXBblJWBJo2i1TYDWdKQyWREE%2Bi5OlKWBOrVWhaVBW66ERUm/l9VtAlGvVfU5vRXV5W29l7W9K1NkdWuoE9SufUDUNUOiONELrOH02zUQxALaQS2YRDF7cBtznSDtiF7QgGolpQPtPS9b3%2B1BijfQhd6Ps%2BR0nWdF1XRYN13Q9K7y%2B9EGfT9md/fAKHoeDOGg/hifEZkRjABYkhw9RHhIxJqPo5zG6Y7x/GCUTuYE3jUmK2T8kRlTymL%2BQ9D05p2m6cQ%2Bb6azRkmWZlE81Z/O8AIgEOWIaeua4EuedLdCy0FKY/kjDIG8AYWYmI0BZF5P5Zgb4Qp5XCpFJ2gg1Zu0qvrbWtUtaZXQY1BWYVaBlWyCgy2iCiEtCNoIB2JCQjOxoVQpqnszwew0l1NukFNgACUACyw1RpTAsJNKO%2BAY5xwTitHCF4zCp1FunTuFd9pVwAio1RaigJDALiAV63UhKQS%2BnBcuSFe4AwwpIkGeF%2B7VFHt%2Bcek9KLT1opQZG4F56Xwxjcbi2NV54w3qIcSQliY7zkkJSm1NDJ0w0uBRmF8r4s0MqKO%2Bi9uaWT5jZF%2BIAKLvxFrIMWbl4C/x8gA%2BWxVCHK10KQ2Kdg8EaxwYEbBGVDY1ONuQ4htVSmmxtjEd2RUzZ0OoZQ5pHsWosKYWwv2eiVzcJ4UNEaY0hFTRmqI%2BaoxFrLWBrHUYkhZG5PkUYrOOdqiS0ehuQuujwL6NLoY3aldDpqPuSojRrdi4Z0URpSQEyLkd32T0WStElbcCAA%3D) for x86-64 with gcc and clang, and for ARMv7 and AArch64.

```
## GCC9.2 -O3 for x86-64
TAS(std::atomic_flag&):
        mov     eax, 1
        xchg    al, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        ret
TAS_bool(std::atomic<bool>&):
        mov     eax, 1
        xchg    al, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        test    al, al
        setne   al                      # missed optimization, doesn't need to booleanize to 0/1
        ret
clear(std::atomic_flag&):
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], 0
        mfence                          # memory fence to drain store buffer before future loads
        ret
clear_relaxed(std::atomic_flag&):
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], 0      # x86 stores are already mo_release, no barrier
        ret
bool_clear(std::atomic<bool>&):
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], 0
        mfence
        ret
```

Note that `xchg` is also an efficient way to do a `seq_cst` store on x86-64, usually more efficient than the `mov` + `mfence` that gcc uses.  Clang uses `xchg` for all of these (except the relaxed store).

Amusingly, clang re-booleanizes to 0/1 after the xchg in `atomic_flag.test_and_set()`, but GCC instead does it after `atomic<bool>`.  clang does a weird `and al,1` in TAS_bool, which would treat values like `2` as false.  It seems totally pointless; the ABI guarantees that a `bool` in memory is always stored as a `0` or `1` byte.

For ARM, we have `ldrexb` / `strexb` exchange retry loops, or just `strb` + `dmb ish` for the pure store.  Or AArch64 can use `stlrb   wzr, [x0]` for `clear` or assign-false to do a sequential-release store (of the zero-register) without needing a barrier.

Answer (score 0):

On most/sane architectures an interrupt can happen after or before a hardware instruction is executed. Not "in between" it's execution. So either the instruction "happens" (ie. with "side effects") or does not happen.

For example a 16bit architecture most probably has hardware instructions to operate on 16bit variables with a single instruction. So incrementing a 16bit variable will be a single instruction. Storing a value in a 16bit variable will be a single instruction. Etc. Locking is not needed for 16bit variables, as the increment either happens or does not happen, atomically. It's impossible on this architecture to observe the "mid execution" state of an increment of 16bit variable. It is a single instruction. It can't be interrupted "in between" by any signal and interrupt.

A 16-bit architecture may lack instruction to increment a 64-bit variable in a single instruction. It may need many, many instructions to do operations on 64-bit variables. So operations on `std::atomic<uint64_t>` need additional synchronization instruction inserted by the compiler to implement it's functionality, to implement synchronization with other `std::atomic` variables, etc.

But operations on 16bit variables on this architecture are single instructions, the compiler doesn't need to do anything with them, the side effects will always be visible everywhere after the instruction executes.

So `atomic_flag` is most probably just a variable that has the size of the word on a particular processor. This is so that this processor can operate on this variable with single instructions. In practice that is an `int`, but `int` is not guaranteed to correspond to the word size of the processor and accesses `int` handles are not guaranteed to be atomic. I believe typically `atomic_flag` is the same as [`sig_atomic_t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Types.html) from posix ([posix docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html)). Additional `atomic_flag` constraints it's operations to `bool`-ish like only: clear, set and notify.

Comment: *as the increment either happens or does not happen, atomically* that would be true for a pure store, but not an increment on a multi-core system.   See [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) - special instructions are needed to make RMW operations atomic (like x86 `lock add word [mem], 1` for 16-bit operand-size atomic increment, in any mode.  i.e. `clear` can be atomic "for free" by using a word-sized or smaller size for the type, but `test_and_set` requires some kind of special support that compilers wouldn't normally use when compiling `tmp=v; v=newval;`

Comment: **TL:DR: atomicity WRT. *interrupts* is only sufficient for atomicity on a uniprocessor (single core) system.**