# Critical section control with atomics

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, atomic, critical-section

For some reason I got in my head that

```
if (someAtomicBool) return;
someAtomicBool = false;
```

Is adequate control for a critical section. This is not the case, right? I think the correct way to do this and achieve the functionality I'm looking for is to check if a mutex is locked or something.

Comment: Nope. Immediately after the test, before `someAtomicBool` can be changed, some other thread comes along does the same test and also find it's safe to proceed.

Comment: Mutual exclusion (taking a lock and entering a critical section) requires either an atomic RMW (like [test-and-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set)), or schemes like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm which need sequential consistency and an array of entries for each thread, so max number of threads must be known ahead of time, etc.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm is another such algorithm.

Comment: C++ `std::atomic` provides `std::atomic_flag` which supports `test_and_set`, which can actually be implemented in terms of a few different HW ops, like an actual TAS instruction, an atomic exchange, an atomic compare_exchange, or may be implemented with load-linked / store-conditional on ISAs that provide that instead of single-instruction RMWs.  See also: [Why does C/C++ not have a atomic flag test\_and\_clear?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77929368)

Comment: Found a near-exact duplicate that asks about `if(!executing){     executing = true; ... ; executing = false; }` with `atomic<bool>`, with answers that explain how that doesn't work.